# Placing widget to menu

Tags: menus, widgets

is there any way to display widget in menu. Actually what i want is "site stat" in the menu. (black area) At the right. [link](http://www.gelsor.com)

Answer (score 2):

you can register  a new sidebar, add it to the menu area and then add a widget to it:
you can register a sidebar by adding this function to your functions.php:

```
register_sidebar( array(
        'name' => __( 'Site Stat Widget'),
        'id' => 'stat-widget',
        'description' => __( 'The Site Stat Widget'),
        'before_widget' => '<li id="%1$s" class="widget-container %2$s">',
        'after_widget' => '</li>',
        'before_title' => '<h3 class="widget-title">',
        'after_title' => '</h3>',
    ) );
```

And add the function below to the menu area (i believe within the #openclosecontent div probably in header.php) :

```
<?php dynamic_sidebar( 'stat-widget' ); ?>
```

If you do it right you'll see a new sidebar in your widget page in the admin area where you can add the widget you want.

Comment: Eyal thanks for your help, it worked. but i still need some more tip. as you see from my site the widget is in the menu but how am i going to make it right, not under the menu text, in the same order and different color. when i try to change color,margin and size it automatically changes punch of staf with it

Comment: 1907, this is not a support forum. Now you are asking for a CSS issue that should be placed at StackOverflow. Also, when a question is correctly answered you should mark it as such. Please, read the [FAQ](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/faq).

Comment: since it an easy one just give float:right to #sofa_stats-3. but it will still show above the menu and not in the same line. you can try to move the widget within the #globalnavi to make it in the same line but i am not sure about this one.